# How to write newline in a file?

Tags: python

I'm trying to write in a file:

```
for i in range(0,3):
    f.write(str(l[i])+"\n")
```

when I open the .txt file with notepad the inputs aren't separated by a newline space.

Comment: `os.linesep` is less and less useful, provided you're using text mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your file is probably open as *binary* mode, using Python 2.

Avoid those linefeed issues by opening the file in *text* mode, not *binary* (`"wb"`, which is allowed in python 2 with text):

```
with open("foo.txt","w") as f:
    for i in range(0,3):
        f.write(str(l[i])+"\n")
```

this is portable on any system, but is really interesting on Windows.

On Windows, text mode issues an extra `\r` carriage return char, so basic programs like `notepad` understand that there's a line break (which is natively `\r\n` on windows). This carriage return char is transparent (won't get in your way) if you use `"r"` for reading too.

Python 3 opening modes are way clearer: it's not possible to open a file as binary and write text in it. So it's almost impossible to do such mistakes, which can be deadly when done the other way round. (like the infamous writing binary data as text which "corrupts" the file, replacing all `10` chars by `13`+`10`)

Comment: Thanks but when I read the output file the items are separated by two new lines.Why?

Comment: if `l` has been read from a file, it already contains the newline. In that case, no need to write an extra newline. Just do `f.write(l[i])`